# How to get avg cpu, disk, memory usage in prometheus (promql) of my linux and windows servers #prometheus #grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, prometheus-node-exporter, grafana-alerts

How to get avg cpu, disk, memory usage in prometheus (promql) of my linux and windows nodes ?

#prometheus #grafana

Please guide me a little bit, I have tried lot of techniques but unable to measure.

Answer (score 0):

#Linux:

1. Install the Prometheus (and start the services/localhost:9090)
2. Install the Node-exporter (and start the services/localhost:9100)
3. Install the Grafana (and start the services/localhost:3000)
4. Set the host into Prometheus configuration file (restart the prometheus service)(prometheus.yml)
5. Check the node was detected or not into prometheus targets (localhost:9090)
6. Start the Grafana web dashboard (localhost:3000)
7. Configure the Prometheus data-source into the Grafana
8. Import the node-exporter dashboard into the Grafana (https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860-node-exporter-full/) (by using dashboard ID only or using JSON file)
9. You may modify the query as per requirement (https://blog.ruanbekker.com/cheatsheets/prometheus/)